# Titan with Elasticsearch backend: None of the configured nodes are available: []

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, titan, gremlin

I try to run Titan 1.0.0 with Cassandra 3.0.1 backend and Elasticsearch 2.1.1 as the index backend.

After invoking Gremlin
`g = TitanFactory.open('/opt/titan/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')`

I have the following error message:

```js
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:460)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:147)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1805)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:123)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:279)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:198)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClusterAdminClient.health(AbstractClusterAdminClient.java:127)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health.ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.doExecute(ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.<init>(ElasticSearchIndex.java:201)
        ... 53 more
```

The following is the configuration settings in titan-cassandra-es.properties.

```js
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=10.132.x.x
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=10.132.x.x
index.search.client-only=true
```

I have run telnet tests to both port 9200 and 9300 with no problem. do i need to specify my elasticsearch cluster.name?

Please help, 
thanks.

Comment: Titan 1.0.0 is not compatible with Cassandra 3.x. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846691/titan-1-0-0-hadoop1-compatibilty-issues-with-apache-cassandra-3-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out elasticsearch 2.1 is not compatible with Titan 2.1.1. The solution is to use elasticsearch 1.5.1