# titan-1.0.0-hadoop1 compatibilty issues with apache-cassandra-3.2

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, cassandra-2.0, titan

I am trying to connect **titan-1.0.0-hadoop1** with **apache-cassandra-3.2**.

I am using following " titan-cassandra-myfile.properties ":

```
storage.cassandra-config-dir=titan-1.0.0-   hadoop1/conf/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=localhost
```

When I use gremlin to execute following command:

`g=TitanFactory.open("/path to titan/ titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/conf/titan-cassandra-myfile.properties");`

I am getting following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation:   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
>       at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:144)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
>       ... 42 more
>       Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:572)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:291)
>       ... 47 more
>       Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10000(10000), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:231)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:198)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:84)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:117)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.executeSchemaChangeOperation(ThriftClusterImpl.java:146)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.internalCreateKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:321)
>       at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.addKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:294)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:567)
>       ... 48 more
>   ```

When I use same configurations with  **apache-cassandra-1.2.5**  and **titan-all-0.3.1** , the above config works and it creates a graph.

Please suggest some solution on this , whether is this a compatibility issue or I am doing something wrong.

Thanks,
Laxmikant

Answer (score 4):

**Titan 1.0** has been released using **Cassandra 2.1.9**. I'm almost sure that it's not compatible with **Cassandra 3.x** because there was a storage engine re-write

See here: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/pom.xml#L65

Comment: Thanks @doanduyhai .

Comment: Hey, One more question, I have created a sample graph and stored it in Cassandra using gremlin. Now if I close the database and I want to access the database through gremlin , how do I do that?